# NSTableView add Button or Any Other custom object

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I Am trying to add Button programatically to NSTableView which is also defined programatically, no luck so far. My latest Code is:

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
        auto dataRow = _tasks[row];
    if([tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"Id"]) {
        NSTextField* text = [[NSTextField alloc] init];
        text.stringValue = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:dataRow[0].c_str()];
        return text;

    } else if([tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"Name"]) {
        NSTextField* text = [[NSTextField alloc] init];
        text.stringValue = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:dataRow[1].c_str()];
        return text;

    } else if([tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"Check"]) {
        NSTableCellView* cellView = [[NSTableCellView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 100)];



        NSPopUpButtonCell* popupButtonCell = [[NSPopUpButtonCell alloc] init];
        [popupButtonCell setPullsDown:YES];
        [popupButtonCell insertItemWithTitle:@"dsadsa1" atIndex:0];
        [popupButtonCell insertItemWithTitle:@"dsadsa2" atIndex:1];

        NSPopUpButton* popupButton = [[NSPopUpButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 100) pullsDown:YES];

        popupButton.cell = popupButtonCell;

        [popupButton insertItemWithTitle:@"dsadsa" atIndex:0];
        [popupButton insertItemWithTitle:@"dsadsa" atIndex:1];

        NSTextField* text = [[NSTextField alloc] init];
        NSTextFieldCell* textCell = [[NSTextFieldCell alloc] initTextCell:@"dsadsad"];
        text.stringValue = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"titleee"];
        text.cell = textCell;

        [cellView addSubview:text];
        [cellView addSubview:popupButton];

        return cellView;

    }
```

the last column is showing empty for some reason

Comment: `objectValueForTableColumn:row` is the wrong API to return a **cell** anyway. In a view based table view *objectValue* is supposed to return the model item for the particular row. I highly recommend to create the button in Interface Builder. It's very easy.

Comment: i don't want to use interface builder, if you have example for programatically doing that, would be great

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't, I usually don't *reinvent the wheel* if there is a more convenient (and more efficient) alternative .

Comment: Views are created in `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:`.